# c++ array of type " class student"

Tags: c++, arrays

i have this c++ assignment....and iam having a bit of a problem since iam used more to c#
i created a class student in order to create an array with different elements...the problem  is how can i see the array in the functions in the class part...inorder to fill it with students details and display it..here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class student{
private:
    int id, age;
        string fname, lname, cob;
        char s;
        int stdcount;
public:

    void addstd();
    void searchstd(int n);
    void displayinfo();
    void deletestd(int n);
    void displayrange();
    void modifyinfo(int n);
};

void student::addstd()
{
    cout<<"Enter ID Number"<<endl;
    cin>>id;
    cout<<"Enter First Name"<<endl;
    cin>>fname;
    cout<<"Enter last Name"<<endl;
    cin>>lname;
    cout<<"Enter age"<<endl;
    cin>>age;
    cout<<"Enter student's Sex(F or M) "<<endl;
    cin>>s;
    cout<<"Enter Country of birth"<<endl;
    cin>>cob;
}
void student::displayinfo()
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        cout<<ar[i];
    }
}
void student::searchstd(int m)
{
}


void main()
{
    student s;
    student std[100];
    int choice;
    do{

    cout << "-----------Menu------------" << endl;
        cout << "  1. Add a student " << endl;
        cout << "  2. Search for student by ID " << endl;
        cout << "  3. Display all students information   " << endl;
        cout << "  4. Remove a students  " << endl;
        cout << "  5. Display students aged between 34 - 50  " << endl;
        cout << "  6. Modify a student's information         " << endl;
        cout << "  7. Exit         " << endl;
        cout << "  Enter your choice 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5,6,7   " << endl;
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                std[i].addstd();
            }
           break;
        case 2:
            int numid;
            cout <<"enter id "<<endl;
            cin>>numid;
            s.searchstd(numid);
           break;
        case 3:
           break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
           break;
        case 6:
           break;
        default:
           cout << "Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7 : " << endl << endl;
    }

    }while(choice!=7);

}
```

Comment: Where is your `ar` array defined?

Comment: why does your Student class contain functions for list management? you should strictly separate the data and routines for: single object, container object, and in/output

Comment: That's a pretty questionable design. Why would a student know anything about an array of students? (BTW: you would have exactly the same problem in C#.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has very little to do with C++ and everything to do with proper design.  Even if you used C#, you would have very little, if any justification for creating a student object as the way you did for C++.

First, as others have mentioned, a student should only know about themself (first name, last name).  It isn't a student's responsibility to keep track of other students.  A very rough design would look like this:

```
#include <string>
 class student {
  private:
     int id, age;
     std::string fname, lname, cob;
     char s;

  public:
     student() {}
     void setId(int n) { id = n; }
     void setFirstName(const std::string& s) { fname = s; }
     void setLastName(const std::string& s) { lname = s; }
     //etc..

     int getId() const { return id; }
     std::string getFirstName() const { return fname; }
     std::string getLastName() const  { return lname; }
    // etc...
};
```

That is all a student should have.  Setting and getting the student's information.  Nothing more, nothing less.  You can embellish this by adding a constructor to easily create an entire student in one call (if you want to do this).  But this is the basic gist of what a student class should look like.

Now you create an array of these students:

```
typedef std::array<student, 100> StudentList;  // creates an array of 100 students.
```

or preferably, a vector< student >, so that it becomes a lot easier to handle:

```
#include <vector>
//..
typedef std::vector<student> StudentList;
```

Then you use StudentList as your array / vector of students.

It then becomes trivial when it comes to display the students -- just go through the array one by one and display the students information.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your `displayInfo` function to take an input

```
void student::displayInfo(student ar[], int numStudents)
{
    for(int i=0;i<numStudents;i++)
    {
        cout<<ar[i]; // if you have << operator defined
    }
}
```

Then in `main` you could say:

```
student std[100];
displayInfo (std, 100); // this is passing your array in (you need to populate it though)
```

Comment: the op should use c++ not c. its questionable to use an array as an argument without passing its length